# Login into github for Phonegap 3.0 in Command line

Tags: github, cordova

I am using **Phonegap 3.0** command line tool **(CLI)** for building  android  app on remote build.
They require github account ,but when I enter my **github** account info but I couldn't login with **github** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GITHUB account are unsupported if you see warning in my ss.

so you should create account in build.phonegap.com

[image]

Comment: If github account are unsupported then Is there a different way to build using other account?

Comment: use this link https://build.phonegap.com/plans/free-adobeid register here or use your exiting ADOBE account.

Comment: I created an account on build.phonegap.com and signed in using github. It looks like it uses my email address as my username, but what's my password?

Comment: ok i got it - not only can you not log in with a github account (which I understood literally), you cannot log in with a phonegap account which is linked only to a github account. you need to create an adobe ID and use that to log in

Comment: use this link https://build.phonegap.com/people/edit and mix your info from github with adobe.

Answer (score 0):

You should export the path to the ADT tools, as described in 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

this avoid having to create an account